# Create HTML list from plain text within an XML structure

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, plaintext

I have a XML file in which everything is well structured except for ordered lists. Every list item is tagged as a paragraph `<p>`, with the enumeration added manually: (1). I want to create a valid HTML list from that source.

Using the `xsl:matching-substring` method and regular expressions I was able to extract every list item but I can't seem to find a way to add the surrounding `<ol>` tags.

Here is an example:

XML source:

```
<Content>
    <P>(1) blah</P>
    <P>(2) blah</P>
    <P>(2) blah</P>
</Content>
```

What I have so far:

```
<xsl:variable name="text" select="/Content/*/text()"/>
<xsl:analyze-string select="$text" regex="(\(\d+\))([^(]*)">
    <xsl:matching-substring>    
        <![CDATA[<li>]]><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/><![CDATA[</li>]]>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
```

Output:

```
<li>blah</li>
<li>blah</li>
<li>blah</li>
```

In case you are wondering: output has to be plain text in general, only the contents of the `$text` variable have to be output in HTML. That's why I am using `<![CDATA[]]`.

Comment: The provided code shouldn't produce any result but the following error: "Saxon 9.1.0.5J from Saxonica Java version 1.6.0_31 Stylesheet compilation time: 586 milliseconds
Processing file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre6/bin/marrowtr.xml
Building tree for file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre6/bin/marrowtr.xml using net.sf.saxon.tinytree.TinyBuilder
Tree built in 0 milliseconds

Error on line 6 of marrowtr.xsl:
  XPTY0004: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the @select attribute of
  xsl:analyze-string ("(1) blah", "(2) blah", ...) 
Transformation failed: Run-time errors were reported
"

Comment: @KelvinMackay, Understood. Do notice that the OP is creating *tags* as strings -- this is completely wrong and chances are these strings will not be interpreted as HTML elements but just as strings. XSLT doesn't deal with "tags" but with *nodes*. As result a proper transformation creates elements, not string that happen to be the serializations of these elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**As simple as this**:

**I. XSLT 2.0 solution:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <ol>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </ol>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="P[matches(., '(^\(\d+\)\s*)(.*)')]">
    <li>
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(^\(\d+\)\s*)(.*)">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
              <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </li>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Content>
    <P>(1) blah</P>
    <P>(2) blah</P>
    <P>(2) blah</P>
</Content>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<ol>
    <li>blah</li>
    <li>blah</li>
    <li>blah</li>
</ol>
```

---

**II. XSLT 1.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <ol>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </ol>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "P[starts-with(.,'(')
   and
     floor(substring-before(substring(.,2), ')'))
    =
     substring-before(substring(.,2), ')')
    ]">
    <li>
         <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., ') ')"/>
    </li>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), the same correct result is produced**:

```
<ol>
   <li>blah</li>
   <li>blah</li>
   <li>blah</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a solution, but a suggested slight improvement on Dimitre's solution.

(1) The template match condition for the XSLT 2.0 solution can be simplified to ...

```
<xsl:template match="P[matches(., '^\(\d+\)')]">
```

Having said that, the regex for the xsl:analyze-string should remain as it is.

(2) Possibly, this is outside the scope of the question, but the question reads like html is the intended output, and so the html xsl:output method should be suggested to the OP.